# "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" with JDK 8 installed

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I just got a new computer and decided that I wanted to start dipping my toe in creating minecraft mods. Super new, have no idea what I'm doing, following a guide as I go.

I've downloaded Open JDK 8, downloaded eclipse, downloaded and unzipped the forge JDK kit, imported the project as an existing gradle project, ran the genEclipseRuns gradle task, imported the launch configs of runClient and runServer, made sure I was running the right version of Minecraft in the Environments, go to run the project and I always get the following error.

```
2021-01-05 20:37:26,828 main WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
[20:37:26] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--gameDir, ., --launchTarget, fmluserdevserver, --fml.mcpVersion, 20201102.104115, --fml.mcVersion, 1.16.4, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.forgeVersion, 35.1.4]
[20:37:26] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 8.0.6+85+master.325de55 starting: java version 15.0.1 by Oracle Corporation
[20:37:27] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch services [minecraft,fmldevdata,fmldevclient,fmldevserver,fmluserdevserver,fmluserdevdata,testharness,fmlclient,fmluserdevclient,fmlserver]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler (file:/C:/Users/Shelby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/cpw.mods/modlauncher/8.0.6/70155a85837ebb17d36815ab4d12a3b464963df8/modlauncher-8.0.6.jar) to field java.util.jar.Manifest.jv
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[20:37:27] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found naming services : [srgtomcp]
[20:37:27] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchPluginHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch plugins: [mixin,eventbus,object_holder_definalize,runtime_enum_extender,capability_inject_definalize,accesstransformer,runtimedistcleaner]
[20:37:27] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Discovering transformation services
...
```

Further on, there is also this error:

```
...
[20:37:28] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.ModSorter/LOADING]: Found 2 mandatory requirements
[20:37:28] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.ModSorter/LOADING]: Found 0 mandatory mod requirements missing
Exception in thread "main" [20:37:28] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1048]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory
[20:37:28] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1048]:   at net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModEngine.loadCoreMod(CoreModEngine.java:48)
[20:37:28] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1048]:   at net.minecraftforge.coremod.CoreModProvider.addCoreMod(CoreModProvider.java:12)
[20:37:28] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1048]:   at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
...
```

I have been pulling my hair out for the last hour trying to get this to work, I have uninstalled everything, reinstalled everything, restarted my computer, removed changed the JDK environments of the launch configs manually, anything I can think of.

All other instances on google I find say that I need to not have a later installation of JDK, that I have to have JDK 8, but I have never had another version.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You tell Eclipse about different versions of Java in the Preferences in the 'Java > Installed JREs' page. Make sure it knows about your Java 8. Then look at the Java Build Path in your project Properties and make sure it is using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no familiarity with deveoping mods for Minecraft. In attempting to help, I am reponding purely from a Java development perspective.

1. I think your first 'error' is probably not relavent, its not actually an error, its a warning, which does not stop the program from running.
2. The second error is probably the one preventing you from proceeding. It is an exception. It says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory` which means Java cannot find a class definition which is being referenced. I looked up this class in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory.html) and it says `Since: 1.8u40` which means it was only introduced for the first time in Java 8 update 40. If you have Java 8 with an update version less than 40, your code will not work.

You can check your java version by typing `java -version` at a command line.
On my system, when I run this command, I get

```
PS C:\> java -version                                                                                                   
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

This tells me im running Java 8 (1.8) update 261

The other thing is that you have mentioned that you are using Open JDK 8. My install is Oracle Java, which I downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html#JDK8). Im not sure if `NashornScriptEngineFactory` is available in your version of Open JDK, or even if its available at all, how ever, this [page](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/236) suggests that it has been implementd. Im not sure, but I think it says you might need OpenJDK 9, but I'm not sure.

I hope I have been able to help a little. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this led me down a loooong rabbit hole though. If you have any additional help I'd be happy to take it!

I found out the version I have been using is NOT 1.8, but 15 from OpenJDK (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.15...). I went to the JRE Environments and Compiler to change it to 1.8, but it would continue to stay in 15. I uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse hoping that would help, but it is continuing to show up. 

I am going to continue tomorrow when I am not as frustrated though! Thank you so much, your one comment on the version has found my entire problem.